# Prevent image stretching in Kivy canvas

Tags: kivy

### The situation

I've made a Widget in Kivy in order to animate an image.

```
<AnimatedImage>:
    pos_hint: root.pos_hint
    size: root.size
    size_hint: .3, .3
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'images/image.png'
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1]
            size: root.size[0], 435. / 770 * root.size[0]
```

As you can see in the last line, I used the image ratio to calculate the rectangle size.

### The problem

I would like to load different images and size the widget in adjustment.

### What didn't work

Using Image instead of Widget. I was not able to animate the Image size_hint using Animation object.

Thanks!

Comment: So what bit can't you do? The problem is just updating the aspect ratio scaling?

Comment: Yep, I want the aspect ratio to be read from the image.